# interrogative sentence with two clauses?

Tags: clauses, interrogatives

There is this question and it is confusing me:

**Has the applicant completed, or is currently enrolled in any other studies or training outside XYZ (country name)?**

The answer is:

**Yes or No**

Actually, I have completed. So what should be the answer (yes or no) and why?

Comment: Your answer to the whole question is "yes" because your answer to *at least one part* of the question is "yes".  The "or" combines the two clauses into *alternatives*.  Only someone who answers "no" to *both* parts should answer "no" to the whole question.

Comment: It might help if the sentence was grammatical!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should answer "Yes."

"Or" in English is usually what is called in logic a non-exclusive "or." That means that "A or B" is considered true if A is true but not B, B is true but not A, or both A and B are true.

Sometimes context or vocabulary will entail that a simple "or" is to be understood as exclusive. For a simple example, the sentence "That was either a zebra or a giraffe" clearly intends an exclusive "or" because nothing is both a zebra and a giraffe. But the general case is that "or" without qualification is non-exclusive. The sentence "The quantitative requirement may be met by taking a year of mathematics or physics" does not mean that taking both math and physics will fail to meet the requirement.

Some people may interpret "either X or Y" as an exclusive "or." Unfortunately that usage is not universal. "Either X or else Y" is one way to specify an exclusive "or." Another is "A or B, but not both."

It is a lexical deficiency in English that it lacks a very sharp division between exclusive "or" (in Latin "aut X aut Y") and non-exclusive (in Latin "vel").

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this is a combination of two question rather than a single question. The two questions are:

1. Has the applicant completed [...]? **(A)**
2. Or is he/she currently enrolled in any other studies or training outside XYZ (country name)?

These are two yes/no questions.

When these two questions are combined into a single question by changing the punctuation, each of the two parts requires an answer. For example, "No, he/she has not completed [...] and he/she is not enrolled in (...)."

Comments:

- **(A)** The verb *to complete* requires a direct object; the original question has no direct object (what has been completed?) and is therefore syntactically incorrect.
- The second part of the original sentence requires a subject, e.g.: "(...) or is **he/she** currently enrolled ..." The combined sentence has two subjects (both referring to the same person) and two main verbs.

Comment: I agree with you completely that the question is badly framed because it combines two logically distinct questions. I further agree that, if reported correctly, the sentence is incorrectly punctuated. A comma after "in" would give a direct object to "complete." But the correct answer in English to the question "Is A or B true" is "yes" unless both A and B are false.

Comment: @JeffMorrow When you answer "yes", won't the other person ask, "Yes, what?"

Comment: Perhaps they will. Perhaps they will not. In the scenario outlined, the questioner will ask that follow-up question only if the distinction is important for the questioner's purpose. As the original question was framed, it seems likely that the distinction is NOT important to the questioner. If I ask "Did you successfully complete at least one year of math or physics," I I may not care at all which course was taken or whether courses in both fields were taken.

Comment: I get the feeling this is on a paper form, so there likely won't be any follow-on question. The person reading the form simply wants to know if the person **is currently taking** or **has previously taken** studies/training. (It doesn't matter which; just answer "yes" or "no".)